# How can I scrape this table properly or order this data properly so that it's not a bunch of mumbo jumbo and organize it in a csv file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_stats():
    url = f'https://dsebd.org/dse_close_price_archive.php?startDate=2021-08-28&endDate=2023-08-28&inst=REPUBLIC&archive=data'
    content = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    rate = soup.find("table", class_="table table-bordered background-white").get_text()

    with open("stats.csv", 'w') as file:
        file.write(rate)
    return rate


get_stats()
```

This is the code I have so far. This is the output I get: https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/98ddcd6f

I tried grabbing it with beautifulsoup4 as you can see in the code but I just get a bunch of mumbo jumbo with no clue on how to organize this. Thank you to anyone who can help me!

Comment: What are you expecting the CSV file to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table into pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://dsebd.org/dse_close_price_archive.php?startDate=2021-08-28&endDate=2023-08-28&inst=REPUBLIC&archive=data"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.select("table:not(:has(table))")[-2]

all_data = []
header = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in table.select("th")]
for row in table.select("tr")[1:]:
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    all_data.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=header)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
   #        DATE TRADING CODE CLOSEP*   YCP
0  1  2023-08-28     REPUBLIC      36  35.9
1  2  2023-08-27     REPUBLIC    35.9  35.3
2  3  2023-08-24     REPUBLIC    35.3  35.9
3  4  2023-08-23     REPUBLIC    35.9  36.7
4  5  2023-08-22     REPUBLIC    36.7  36.7
```

Comment: thank u very much, @Andrej Kesely

i can't upvote it but i would if icould

Comment: why does it only take the first 5 though? @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @agaggagaga It prints first 5 rows of the dataframe because I'm using `.head()`, you can use [`.to_csv(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) method to save the dataframe to CSV file (you must supply correct parameters)